# What is the difference between the two Pentax 50-200mm DA lenses?

Tags: lens, pentax

Pentax offers two DA zoom lenses with a 50-200mm range:

[smc PENTAX DA 50-200mm F4-5.6 ED WR](http://www.pentaximaging.com/camera-lenses/smc_PENTAX_DA_50-200mm_F4-5.6_ED_WR/)

[smc PENTAX DA 50-200mm F4-5.6 ED](http://www.pentaximaging.com/camera-lenses/smc_PENTAX_DA_50-200mm_F4-5.6_ED/)

The only obvious difference I see between them is that one is weather sealed and the other is not. However, they each list for $249.95 on the Pentax web store. This leads me to suspect that there must be other differences to make the non-weather sealed lens competitive at that price. What am I missing?

Comment: For future reference for you: http://kmp.bdimitrov.de/index.html is a great source for K-mount lens info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to me to be the same optical design. Both have 11 elements in 10 groups, with one extra-low-dispersion glass element and two aspherical elements.

I have no idea why you'd buy the non-WR version when buying it separately — but, I think most people don't get it that way. I just looked, and both B&H Photo and Adorama don't carry it individually. You only get it as part of a kit with a new camera body. So, the question really is: why does Pentax USA bother listing in their web store?

I can only guess, but my guess is: they have some in stock, so sure, why not list 'em, but they don't want to undercut the already-quite-low price of the WR version, so they just put it at the same price.

Comment: Another possible explanation of the pricing anomalies is that they were bought into stock at different times at different price points or exchange rates.

Comment: @labnut: makes sense, but at some point don't you have to cut your loses?

Answer (score 1):

**Obviously the 'WR' part is the headline difference.** The optical construction is the same though..

Having held both for a while though, I can tell you that the **WR version feels much more durable**. It has a more steady feel and very smooth focus and zoom. Not that the non-WR is poor but there is an easily notable difference.

If you can get the WR for the same price as the non-WR, buy it, smile and don't ask too many questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

The original version of the DA 50-200mm did not have the weather resistant feature - that came in a later version. It would be extremely odd to find the old one for sale as a new item, it was obsoleted by the WR. They have the same optical formula.

Comment: As you can see from the question, Pentax USA is indeed selling the non-WR version as a new item. For the same price, no less.

Comment: @mattdm, it's understandable that the factory would be stuck with old stock when a better version came out at the same price. I'd guess they're forced by contractual obligation to offer them at list price.

Comment: Possibly. Who knows what Hoya / Pentax Japan requires of Pentax USA.

Comment: Sorry, but both Pentax and Bojidar Dimitrov (a great source for k-mount lens info) disagree with you. The WR version is newer but both are still in production, apparently, though Pentax is a little confused on the issue.